# File displaying only one form of request and response

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am generating a file where it should output 2 various requests and 2 various responses from different SOAP Request steps which are:

```
TestRegion
TestRules
```

However I noticed the file is just generating  `TestRegion` request and response 2 times each over. For each request it displays  `TestRegion` request and for each response it's displaying  `TestRegion` response. Why is it doing this and how can I get the correct request and responses to show? it does display the hard coded strings correct like `TESTREGION REQUEST:` and then later on `TEST REGION RESPONSE`, but the request and response is incorrect.

```
def testRegionRequest = context.expand( '${${TestRegion}#Request}'  )
def testRegionResponse = context.expand( '${${TestRegion}#Response}'  )
def testRulesRequest = context.expand( '${${TestRules}#Request}'  )
def testRulesResponse = context.expand( '${${TestRules}#Response}'  )


def fileName = "XXX.txt"
def logFile = new File(fileName)

//Draws a line
def drawLine(def letter = '=', def count = 70) { letter.multiply(count)}

def testResult = new StringBuffer() 
testResult.append drawLine('-', 60) + "\n\n" 
testResult.append "\n\nTEST REGION REQUEST:\n\n" 
testResult.append(testRegionRequest.toString())
testResult.append "\n\n" + drawLine('-', 60) + "\n\n" 
testResult.append "\n\nTEST REGION RESPONSE:\n\n" 

testResult.append(testRegionResponse.toString())
testResult.append "\n\n" + drawLine('-', 60) + "\n\n" 
testResult.append "\n\nTEST RULES REQUEST:\n\n"
testResult.append(testRulesRequest.toString())
testResult.append "\n\n" + drawLine('-', 60) + "\n\n" 
testResult.append "\n\nTEST RULES RESPONSE:\n\n"
testResult.append(testRulesResponse.toString())

// Now create and record the result file
logFile.write(testResult.toString())
```

Comment: BruceyBandit, have you tried the solution below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have incorrect values used in the `context.expand`

Change from:

```
${${SearchRegion}#Request}
```

To:

```
${SearchRegion#Request}
```

And the same is applicable to other properties as well.